# How to do combine 2 list without duplicate in Jmeter?

Tags: loops, jmeter, nested-loops, jmeter-5.0, interleave

I want to make an automated order and payment. There's a list of Order and a list of Payment, and I want to use all of the payment for all the order.

Order List :

1. Order A
2. Order B
   .
   .

Payment list :

1. Payment A
2. Payment B
   .
   .

I try using interleave controller for 1 order to use all payment. But it's resulting for me to copy paste the interleave into the amount of order that I have and it's difficult to maintain if I have many order.

```
Order A
- Add product
- Interleave controller
-- Payment A
-- Payment B
Order B
- Add product
- Interleave controller
-- Payment A
-- Payment B
```

So I change to putting interleave for the order and the payment.

```
Interleave Controller (Order)
- Order A
- Order B
.
.
Interleave Controller (Payment)
- Payment A
- Payment B
.
.
```

But the result is

```
Order A
Payment A
Order B
Payment B
```

What I want is the order can get all of the payment without duplicate the payment. And have the result to be:

```
Order A
Payment A
Order A
Payment B
Order B 
Payment A
Order B
Payment B
.
.
and so on
```

Comment: Instead of Interleave Controller, ForEach Controller would be better to choose for your scenario to achieve the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller), in the majority of cases it's better applicable for the kind of loop you're trying to achieve.

If you additionally want to avoid code duplication you can also consider [Test Fragments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) and [Module Controllers](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller).